# Android Screen Sizes for different devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I am new to android development and now i have started developing wallpaper apps.I saw the android developer  page which tells the ratio 3:4:6 or something which i don't understand. Everything is working but the image which i set go off the screen sometimes it gets cropped around the corners and image does not look good. i use the screen size 600*480 in hdpi. Any suggestion about the different size images i should use may be for ldpi,mdpi,hdpi, xhdpi.I want my wallpaper look good in home screens of both tablets and for large size screen mobiles.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

`3:4:6:8` , so if you have `600*480` in hdpi then it should go like this

```
3k:300*240
4k:400*320
6k:600*480
8k:800*640
```

but since there are multiple device with same dp but different screen size, you can never quitly fit for every device

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got another question regarding the home screen size dimensions.c Which methods are used to get the minimum width and height parameters of the devices and how do i use those parameters in my bitmap methods or set wallpaper methods..?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got another question.Could You please tell me which methods can i use know the home screen dimensions and how do i get the minimum width and minimum height values? Which method should i use to set my bitmap image relative the min.height and min.width as my home screen wallpaper..

Comment: what you mean by minimum dimensions? there is only one dimension for a device, if you want to get width and height of a device you can refer to this answer, as it tells very widely http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/1936366